# How to set up URLs with wildcards or variables

Tags: google-optimize

In Google optimize we are trying to get tests done towards a web page that includes variables in it such as:

`https://yyy.com/lang/{lang}/{city}/list`

....where list would have variants like `list_vA`, `list_vB` etc.. for re-direct testing.

So far in the interface of Google Optimize we have seen that there are multiple conditions available to do different things but we're not sure which ones apply to that case and our tests don't work.

Anybody could provide a tutorial for how to set up the correct editor link as well as how to set up the re-direct URLs correctly?